# How to prove an identity involving a hypergeometric function?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions, special-functions

How to prove with the help of *Mathematica* the following statement?

$$ {}_2F_1\left(\frac{2}{3},\frac{2}{3};\frac{5}{3};-1\right)=\frac{\pi -3 \sqrt{3} \log \left(\sqrt[3]{2}-1\right)-6 \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1+2^{2/3}}{\sqrt{3}}\right)}{3 \sqrt{3}}
$$

```
FullSimplify[
 Hypergeometric2F1[2/3, 2/3, 5/3, -1] 
   - ((\[Pi] - 6 ArcTan[(1 + 2^(2/3))/Sqrt[3]] - 3 Sqrt[3] Log[-1 + 2^(1/3)])/(3 Sqrt[3]))]
```

is returned without simplifications.

Background:
There are several reasons to study this value. On the one side, it can be easily represented as a definite integral:
$$
{}_2F_1\left(\frac{2}{3},\frac{2}{3};\frac{5}{3};-1\right) = \frac{\Gamma(5/3)}{\Gamma(2/3)} \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(1 + t) (2 + t)^{2/3}} dt.
$$
On the other side, there are many cases where hypergeometric functions can be evaluated at $z = −1$ by using a transformation to change $z = −1$ to $z = 1$ and then using Gauss's theorem, which Mathematica certainly "knowns", to evaluate the result. Quadratic and cubic transformations come into question, but I cannot seem to find the right identity. I hope that *Mathematica* knows these transformations internally.

Comment: `Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 500},
 Hypergeometric2F1[2/3, 2/3, 
    5/3, -1] - ((\[Pi] - 6 ArcTan[(1 + 2^(2/3))/Sqrt[3]] - 
       3 Sqrt[3] Log[-1 + 2^(1/3)])/(3 Sqrt[3])) // N[#, 100] &]`

Comment: What for? Isn't it art for art's sake?

Comment: The method used [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/286936/evaluating-5f-4-left1-1-1-1-1-frac32-2-2-2-frac14-right) might be useful.

Comment: @yarchik: Are your reasons solid? You still don't answer "what for?". You say only about similar identities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an identity $15.6.1$ in  [NIST Digital Library of Mathematical Functions](https://dlmf.nist.gov/15.6) or in [Wolfram Functions Site](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/07/01/01/0001/) (mind appropriate definitions therein!)
$$_2F_1\left(a,b;c;z\right)=\frac{\Gamma\left(c\right)}{\Gamma\left(b\right)\Gamma\left(c-b%
\right)}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{t^{b-1}(1-t)^{c-b-1}}{(1-z\;t)^{a}}\,\mathrm{d}t$$

*Mathematica* knows this identity

```
FullSimplify[ Hypergeometric2F1[a, b, c, z] == (Gamma[
  c]/(Gamma[b] Gamma[c - b])) Integrate[(t^(b - 1) (1 - t)^(c - b - 1)
    )/(1 - t z)^a, {t, 0, 1}], 
  Re[c] > Re[b] > 0 && Abs[Arg[1 - z]] < Pi && Re[z] <= 1]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

We are interested in $a=b=\frac{2}{3},\;c=\frac{5}{3},\;z=-1\;$ case.

```
Integrate[1/(t^(1/3) (1 + t)^(2/3)), {t, 0, 1}]
```

> ```
> 3/2 Hypergeometric2F1[2/3, 2/3, 5/3, -1]
> ```

We can change the variable $t$ into $x$: $\quad t^{\frac{2}{3}}=x$ and so
$$_2F_1\left(\frac{2}{3},\frac{2}{3};\frac{5}{3};-1\right)=\frac{2}{3}\int_0^1 \frac{1}{t^{\frac{1}{3}}(1+t)^{\frac{2}{3}}}\,\mathrm{d}t=\int_0^1 \frac{1}{(1+x^{\frac{3}{2}})^{\frac{2}{3}}}\,\mathrm{d}x$$
The last integral can be simply calculated in *Mathematica 13.0.1*

```
Integrate[1/(1 + x^(3/2))^(2/3), {x, 0, 1}]
```

> ```
> 1/3 (-2 Sqrt[3] ArcCot[(1 + 2 2^(1/3))/Sqrt[3]] - 2 Log[-1 + 2^(1/3)]
>       + Log[1 + 2^(1/3) + 2^(2/3)])
> ```

and in fact we have

```
FullSimplify[
  1/3 (-2 Sqrt[3] ArcCot[(1 + 2 2^(1/3))/Sqrt[3]] - 
         2 Log[-1 + 2^(1/3)] + Log[1 + 2^(1/3) + 2^(2/3)]) == 
  (Pi - 6 ArcTan[(1 + 2^(2/3))/Sqrt[3]] - 3 Sqrt[3] Log[-1 + 2^(1/3)])/(3 Sqrt[3])]
```

> ```
>  True
> ```

i.e.
[image]

Handling of special functions by any computer algebra system brings several issues, e.g. how to get a specific formula among many possibilities when we expect automatic proceeding of the system? This addresses a number of technical problems behind the scene developing an agile computer system. I guess *Mathematica* gets ahead fulfilling these requirements.

**Edit for earlier versions**

I have checked in *version 12.3.1*

```
Integrate[1/(1 + x^(3/2))^(2/3), x]
Integrate[1/(1 + x^(3/2))^(2/3), {x, 0, 1}]
```

> ```
> x Hypergeometric2F1[2/3, 2/3, 5/3, -x^(3/2)]
> Hypergeometric2F1[2/3, 2/3, 5/3, -1]
> ```

Nonetheless we can define:

```
int[x_] := -((2 ArcTan[(Sqrt[3] Sqrt[x])/(Sqrt[x] + 2 (1 + x^(3/2))^(1/3)
  )])/Sqrt[3]) - 2/3 Log[-Sqrt[x] + (1 + x^(3/2))^(1/3)] + 
    1/3 Log[x + Sqrt[x] (1 + x^(3/2))^(1/3) + (1 + x^(3/2))^(2/3)]
```

then

```
int[1] - int[0] // FullSimplify
```

yields the result of `Integrate[1/(1 + x^(3/2))^(2/3), {x, 0, 1}]` in *version 13.0.1* and

```
D[int[x], x] // FullSimplify
```

> ```
>  1/(1 + x^(3/2))^(2/3)
> ```

Comment: What version of Mathematica that are you using? MA 11, for instance, returns result of `Integrate[1/(1 + x^(3/2))^(2/3), {x, 0, 1}]` in hypergeometric form.

Comment: Version 13.0.1 returns as demonstrated above.

Comment: Interesting to know that there has been some development in this direction recently.

Answer (score 0):

Hypergeometric series are the solution family of linear ODE on (0,1) with polynomial coefficients in $x$. Nearly nothing is known in general.

Identities at a point of the argument for fixed paramters, $x=-1$, generally can be verified by the 0th term of series

```
     Series[Hypergeometric2F1[2/3, 2/3, 5/3, 
x] - ((\[Pi] - 6 ArcTan[(1 + 2^(2/3))/Sqrt[3]] - 
   3 Sqrt[3] Log[-1 + 2^(1/3)])/(3 Sqrt[3])), {x, -1, 0}]

SeriesData[x, -1., {}, 1, 1, 1]
```

or by FindRoot

```
  FindRoot[Hypergeometric2F1[2/3, 2/3, 5/3, x] - ((\[Pi] - 6 ArcTan[(1 + 2^(2/3))/Sqrt[3]] - 
           3 Sqrt[3] Log[-1 + 2^(1/3)])/(3 Sqrt[3])), {x, 2}]


   {x -> -1. - 9.14229*10^-20 I}
```

Comment: I am getting `Series::ztest1: Unable to decide whether numeric quantity is equal to zero. Assuming it is.` Do you get some more informative result?

Comment: `Series[Hypergeometric2F1[2/3, 2/3, 5/3, 
   x] - ((\[Pi] - 6 ArcTan[(1 + 2^(2/3))/Sqrt[3]] - 
      3 Sqrt[3] Log[-1 + 2^(1/3)])/(3 Sqrt[3])), {x, -1, 1}]`  works better.

Comment: Things in special functions code are under permanent  development. My results are from vs 13.3.0 installed yesterday. A vs 6 is unable, too.  Workaround: Get Series[ f/value,{x,-1,0}] //N, yieldiing  1.0 with less headache as 0.0

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm just translating Euleros Latin paper De Fractionibus Continuis Observationes, in order to get a feeling of his way of making detections by an extraodinary ability in performeing nearly endless algebraic deformations

[image: Euler Continued Fractions]

applied to the original definition of hypergeometric functions as generalized integrals of the form

$$\int_0^1 \frac {dx}{1+x}  \to \int_0^1 \frac {x^{n-1}\ dx}{(1+x^m)^{\frac{\nu}{\mu}}}$$

I simply tried his way to confirm equality of infinite expressions

[image: Continued Fraction]

For the numerics up to any length, here 128, the continued fractions are equal

```
 ContinuedFraction[N[((\[Pi]-6 ArcTan[(1 + 2^(2/3))/Sqrt[3]]- 
         3 Sqrt[3] Log[-1 + 2^(1/3)])/(3 Sqrt[3])), 128]] ==
 ContinuedFraction[N[Hypergeometric2F1[2/3, 2/3, 5/3, -1], 128]]

     True
```

This is of course no proof, any more than Euler's analysis for guessing the nesting function of the parameters in each fractional step.